# Is spring-webflux affected by the CVE-2023-34053 vulnerability?

Tags: spring, cve

**github/advisories only discloses spring-webmvc is affected**
https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-v94h-hvhg-mf9h

**But spring.io/security mentions spring webflux.**
https://spring.io/security/cve-2023-34053